# Extjs batch load of multiple stores

Tags: extjs, asp.net-web-api, extjs4.2

The story is :

I have a complex form with about 10 combo-boxes. Each of them fetch their binding list from a different store (Restful ones). for example :

- /api/projects/activeyears
- /api/users/managers
- /api/projects/availableDates
- ...

My server side technology (Microsoft WebApi 2) supports batch requests gracefully (described here : http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2012/06/batching-handler-for-web-api.html) .

I want to know if I can do it in ExtJs or not? If yes please tell me how but if your answer is no, can you give me an alternative solution? Requesting 10 different stores makes the form to load too slowly (when all major browsers just make 2 parallel requests at a same time, so I should wait for at least 5  serial requests).

Thanks in advance

Comment: At least you can do this by using the Ext.direct provider which allow you to define a time frame in which all requests get bundled. Anyway it might be interesting to hear more about that topic concerning the other provider

Answer (score 3):

Server-side you can use batch requests (aggregate 2 x 5 requests or 3+3+4). Ideally you return something like:

```
{
    success: true,
    activeyears: [ ... ],
    managers: [ ... ],
    availableDates: [ ... ], 
    ...
}
```

From ExtJS point of view this is an Ajax-request without a connection to a store or proxy.

In `success` you have something like this:

```
Ext.Ajax.request({
    url: '/api/myAggregatedRequest1',
    method: 'GET',
    success: function (result, request) {
        var jsonResp;

        jsonResp = Ext.decode(result.responseText);
        if (jsonResp.success) {
            myActiveYearsStore.loadData(jsonResp.activeyears);
            myManagersStore.loadData(jsonResp.managers);
            myAvailableDatesStore.loadData(jsonResp.availableDates);

            // ... trigger some event

        } else {
            // ... error handling
        }
    },
    failure: function (result, request) {
        // ... error handling
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your workaround. It seems your solution is the best workaround although it forces me to "write" a new api to aggregate my needs.